# Best Practices for building an iOS app with backend data

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, sqlite, postgresql

I am just now learning the iOS SDK and want to know what are the best practices/design patterns for handling all sorts of data.  I see the iOS' core data includes a version os SQLLite that runs on my iPhone/iPad.  How is data typically stored with regards to the device and the server.

For instance, how would an app like Path or Instagram store all their data?  Is it the best practice to store data on the device and sync to a database on a web server? What types of databases are commonly used for this?

(I can clarify anything if need be.)

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: see above comment, but also try AWS and Heroku. Probably two biggest platforms in mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most applications create an API over HTTP, usually using JSON. Most information, though not usually binary files, are stored in some sort of database. Some applications choose an SQL database like MySQL or PostgreSQL, and other choose something that's been classified as a NoSQL database, like MongoDB or Redis.

The choice of the server architecture is irrelevant to the app itself, and you'll see developers swap most of their server technology out from time to time.

Basically, any popular web framework and datastore are going to be fine choices at first, so use whatever you're comfortable with.

Comment: Okay so just a LAMP stack since I'm familar with it would be fine for server side stuff.  But to interact with the MySQL db from the app, use JSON then? I'm also curious on Authentication.

Comment: Look into the best practice for REST APIs, should cover a lot of what you'll be doing

Comment: Thx JeffS. +1 for your help too.